# JasperServer choose DataSource dynamically

Tags: jasperserver

Is it possible to change my datasource dynamically for my reports like a parameter?

I have 2 datasources but i want to choose between them so only need one report for 2 datasources.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Is this question about JasperReports Server?

Comment: Can't you have two exactly equal reports each one pointing to a different dataSource, and put the logic that decides which one to use outside of jasperserver?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.